# word range or \w in negative lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to made regex for extracting word at the place of `Delhi` in text
`sending to: GK Delhi`, where the `sending to:` is fixed and i don't want to capture whatever at the place of `GK`. Actually `GK` will be one word in my case, what i made which should work is: `(?<=sending to: \w )Delhi`, means if word starts with `sending to:` and ends with `Delhi` then return Delhi.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Try adding a `+` (e.g. `(?<=sending to: \w+ )Delhi`)

Comment: @StevenDoggart https://regex101.com/r/iO8lZ5/1

Comment: Are you using PCRE?  You didn't specify.

Comment: @StevenDoggart No, just normal regex

Comment: @AlexShesterov, i have to use it with java

Comment: Normal regex?  There's no such thing.  What regex tool/library/language are you using?

Comment: @Shams, is the `GK` part limited to 2 characters? Is it always 2 characters?

Comment: @AlexShesterov, no it is of variable length but only one word

Comment: Then why use lookarounds? Just use: `sending to:\s*\w+\s*Delhi`. If a match is found, you already know the result: `Delhi`.

Comment: In PCRE, you can use `sending to: \w+ \KDelhi` as a workaround for the limitation where lookarounds must be fixed width.

Comment: @Shams, is using a capturing group an option for you? I.e., are you controlling the code which uses the regex, or only the regex itself?

Comment: I am controlling the code as well.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, sorry but i did. Check the tags in my question and also my comment which says 'with java'.

Comment: @AlexShesterov yeah, just saw that and had already retracted my comment and close vote before your commented :)

Comment: FWIW, in the future, you will have better luck if you use an online regex tester that uses the specific flavor of regex that you need.  regex101 is a great site, but it doesn't currently support Java's regex engine.  There are other online testers that do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points,

1. `\w` matches a *single* word character. Use `\w+` to match one or more or `\w*` to match zero or more word characters.
2. Don't forget about space between `DK` and `Delhi`: `\s+`.
3. Just a note: The `(?<=` construct is the *positive* lookbehind, not negative one.

So the regex could look like this:

```
(?<=sending to:\s*\w+\s+)Delhi
```

Please also note that **arbitrary-length lookbehind is only supported by very few regex engines**, but you didn't say anything about the tool you are using.

---

**Update:**

Java doesn't support arbitrary-length lookbehind expressions. 
The possibilities you have are:

- The matched text will always be `Delhi` (on successful match). So if you are only checking for a match, then you could just use the regex: `sending to:\s*\w+\s+Delhi`.
- If you want to extend the regex to other towns in future, then you could use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The regex would be, for example, `sending to:\s*\w+\s+(Delhi|Mumbai)` and in Java code you would get the city name via [`matcher.group(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29).

Please post your actual Java code of how you are using the regex if you want a more detailed advice.